# Template Function using Pointers

Tags: c++, templates, pointers

am I doing something fundamentally wrong here? I'm playing around with templates and pointers but I'm getting errors here.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template <class T>
void ChangeValue(T*, T);

int main()
{
int x = 51;

ChangeValue(&x, 7);

std::cout << x;

float y = 5.1;

ChangeValue(&y, 7.9);

std::cout << y;
}

template <class T>
void ChangeValue(T* Value, T NewValue)
{
    *Value = NewValue;
}
```

Comment: What errors are you getting? Without posting the errors, this isn't a [mcve]

Comment: Thanks Francois, seems it was my misunderstanding. I was under the impression floats and doubles were similar but a double was larger and more precise. How would I improve my example to avoid this error? Is a simple cast sufficient?

Comment: Yes, an MCVE is required. However, in addition, throwing the error message into a websearch also prevents asking redundant questions in the first place.

Comment: @Iloveasparagus I've made an answer from my comment. It contains a possible change to fix your problem.

Answer (score 3):

`&y` has the type `float*` where as `7.9` has the type `double`. The compiler could deduce `T` to be `float` by matching `float*` to `T* Value` or it could deduce `double` by matching `double` to `T NewValue`. For template argument deduction to succeed it must be unambiguous. Try this instead :

```
float y = 5.1f;
ChangeValue(&y, 7.9f);
```

With this change, `T` is deduced to be `float`.

Comment: Change the previous line to float y = 5.1f;  As it stands, the program is telling the compiler to create a double(5.1) and then narrow it to float. VC++ gives the warning, warning C4305: 'initializing': truncation from 'double' to 'float'

Answer (score 3):

When you use:

```
float y = 5.1;
ChangeValue(&y, 7.9);
```

The type of the first argument is `float*` while the type of the second argument is `double`. Hence, the compiler cannot deduce `T`.

One way to fix it is by using:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2 = T1>
void ChangeValue(T1* Value, T2 NewValue)
{
    *Value = NewValue;
}
```

With that, `T2` is deduced from `T1` unless the user explicitly overrides it.

```
float y = 5.1;
ChangeValue<float, double>(&y, 7.9);
```

What would work as long as

```
    *Value = NewValue;
```

is valid for the given `T1` and `T2`.

Comment: Change the previous line to float y = 5.1f;  As it stands, the program is telling the compiler to create a double(5.1) and then narrow it to float. VC++ gives the warning, warning C4305: 'initializing': truncation from 'double' to 'float'